# nspredicate multiple items from an array

Tags: iphone, core-data, nspredicate

how to use NSPredicate to satisfy multiple conditions

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MessageData" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"msg_id = %@",msg_id];

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

i need to fetch objects in which msg_id = values in a array

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do `"msg_id IN %@", array`.