# Compound predicate NSFetchRequest using an Array Swift 2.0 Xcode 7

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data, filter, nsfetchrequest

There's the problem. I have an Array created by the user selecting a set of filters. Is there a way to use an Array as predicate in NSFetchRequest?

Comment: Would the answer in [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6189005/nspredicate-multiple-items-from-an-array) help you out?

Comment: An example might help. But yes, in general you should map your array of filters, transforming it into a valid NSPredicate to fetch whatever objets you are looking for...